# How to call a function every day

Tags: javascript, timer, observable, setinterval, angular5

I managed to call my function every minute or second, but I don't know how to do it in hours and days.
I'm trying to do the call every day in my application.

Here's my code to call a function every 10 seconds

```
this.sub = Observable.interval(10000)
  .subscribe( next: (val) => {
    console.log('called');
    // call my function
  },
  error: err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the interval at which your function is run by changing the number passed to `Observable.interval`. You currently have it set to 10000 milliseconds or 10 seconds, but if you change it to say 60000, then your function will run every hour. You can convert your desired time interval to a number of milliseconds [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=hours%20to%20milliseconds).

Note that the browser window running this code has to stay open for this to work.